# Ear wide Single Sign on with War Exlusion

Tags: web-applications, single-sign-on

I am trying to deploy an Ear file which contains multiple war file. And for my web application, I will need to allow single sign on for most war within my ear file except one. i.e.

my ear:

MY-Ear -WAR-A
       -WAR-B
       -WAR-C
Single Sign On between WAR-A and WAR-B
Seperate authentication for WAR-C

It seems like the tomcat SSO valve doesn't allow such confirguration so I wonder if anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: How can you deploy an EAR file in Tomcat?

Comment: Sorry, by saying tomcat valve I mean the tomcat SSO valve that used by JBoss. I tried to deploy my webapp ear on Jboss

Comment: Well, as I was saying in my answer below, you can do your own JBoss valve that extends the existing one and use that.

Comment: So does that mean there is no existing SSO mechanism to allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

No matter what App server you're using, all of the support some kind of (non-standard, implementation specific) way of making your custom authentication mechanism. I've done this for Tomcat, Jboss, websphere. It's best to take the already existing default component (for the open source ones) and extend it with your own behaviour, then use it in place of that default thingy.